# How can I find a compatible device for a given app on Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, compatibility

There was an app ([Carrot Fantasy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carrot.carrotfantasy), already removed) that I can't install directly from the Play Store on Android tablets. It does run on a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 smartphone, but I have not yet had any luck with any tablet I have tried.

I managed to have the Play Store on a Google Nexus 7 shown the app, but it would not offer an Install option and just said *This app is not compatible with your device.* without any further information.

On other devices such as Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014, the app does not even show up in Play Store.

I have searched for other similar questions, but they usually seem to be asked from the *developer* point of view, i.e. how to modify the app manifest or how to check one's settings in Play Store. They did not provide any insights into what to do on the user side.

Certainly, there must be a way for me as a user to diagnose why the app is deemed incompatible, what specific requirements it has, and then pick an Android device that fulfills those requirements - how?

Comment: Maybe you could contact the app developer and ask what tablets they support.

Comment: @AlE. I believe you are pretty close to the issue. It looks as though it isn't compatible with any tablets. I have 17 different tablet models listed on my account in Play and none of them show up as compatible. Only my phones. (I don't currently have 17 tablets, but I don't remove them from my list on the Play Store for compatibility testing reasons, just like this.)

Comment: @AlE.: As described in my comment below, I now have, and they have merely suggested to download the app from their website rather than using the (presumeably Google-verified) Play Store version. I am looking for a place that compiles information like what abqnm could find out about his or her own tablets, but for lots of tablet types.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have already tested the surest way.  Attempt to download the app and it will specify its compatibility.  You still might not be absolutely sure until you actually try to run the application.

As mentioned in the comment, you can ask the developer or communicate with others who have used the app (via feedback on Google Play or the author's provided web site).

The only way the author can be totally sure is by testing it on every Android or getting feedback from their users.  There are many occasions where based on feedback, the author has to go back to the drawing board to work on glitches to support some devices originally thought to be compatible.

I have a number of Androids.  I just clicked on the install option and find that it's compatible with my Samsung Galaxy S3, my very old phone (the Samsung Galaxy Prevail).  However, it's not compatible with my Samsung Galaxy Tab7 or my Acer-7 tablet.

By the way, good question.  It really appears there should be something specific since Play Google is using some criteria to display compatibility.

Comment: Also keep in mind that app developers can exclude all tablets if they wish (for whatever reason-technical or UX or otherwise). It is highly likely this app has been set to phones only as it doesn't show as compatible on any of the 17 different tablets listed on my Play account.

Comment: I have contacted the author of said app for a list of tablets that support the app. However, they only responded with the recommendation to download and install the app from the Website.

Comment: Before I get a new cell phone, just to install a certain app, I would like to make sure I'm buying a cell phone that could install that app.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455 shows the app developer all the versions they are making available. But how about the end Google Play user, how can they check too?

So we must buy a device, test it. Buy a device, test it... Repeat until we run out of money. PS, assume the developer won't give us an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bypass the Google Play Store altogether. Use an app like Shareit or APK Extractor to transfer the app directly from a device where the app *is* compatible, to the device where Google Play *claims* it's not compatible. I've done this with several apps, and it typically works, in spite of the Play Store's predictions.

Comment: Yes, but what if we're doing this for our head of operations. We can only use official methods.

Comment: This did not work in my case. It was blocked from installing with the same "app isn't compatible with your phone" error.