# Determining compatibility of app on Google Play

Tags: applications, google-play-store, compatibility

Is there a way to see which devices a certain app on Google Play is compatible on?

Edit: to clarify, this is from a user-side perspective.

Comment: Is this from a developer or end-user perspective?

Comment: Are you looking for any devices which are compatible or only your own devices?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I'd be looking for any devices which are compatible (from an end-user perspective)

Comment: Possible dupe: [How can I find a compatible device for a given app on Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75611/44325), [Get app's compatibility matrix from Play Store](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232739/44325)